# Get column values less than max date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a query where I want to get all the values from a table1 prior to the max date from the date column.

I have table1 with column names as id,ord_date.
Further, I want to join it to another table2 with column as id, name

```
SELECT s.title,s.title_id,t.ord_date
FROM titles s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT title_id
          ,max(ord_date) AS ord_date
    FROM sales
    where ord_date < max(ord_date)
    GROUP BY title_id
    ) t ON s.title_id = t.title_id
```

I want solution query showing title from table2 and dates from table1

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: what happened? I am really confused for it as I am working with subqueries for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query.

```
SELECT s.title,s.title_id,t.ord_date
FROM titles s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT x.title_id, max(x.ord_date) AS ord_date
    FROM sales x
    where x.ord_date < (
       select max(m.ord_date) from sales m where m.title_id = x.title_id
    )
    GROUP BY title_id
) t ON s.title_id = t.title_id
```